# Plants that absorb carbon monooxide and other drainage gases

Tags: diseases, plant-recommendations, drainage, nitrogen

I have drainage pits around the house, sometimes the drainage smells comes from the pit but they are odourless gases such as ***carbon monoxide*** which can be harmful and there are other toxic gases such as ***Hydrogen sulphide*** , ***Nitrogen***,***Ammonia*** etc..

[image]

[image]

Are there any particular type of plants or particular plant that can absorb these kinds of gases ?

I also like to mix up plants that can absorb the drainage water from the pit and evaporate it.

As the drainage is near by building wall.I'd like plants which won't affect the building foundation.

I'm mostly looking for outdoor plants but happy to consider indoor plants as well.

Comment: How do you know what gases are being emitted?  Carbon monoxide is heavier than air and has no odor.

Comment: @kevinskio - There's a rotten egg smell that's coming from the drainage pit and I can see cement concrete ring has got blackened as well. So I presume the other toxic gases might be emanating.

Comment: Average person can smell less than 1 ppm of hydrogen sulfide , well below a danger threshold.. When I stir up an aquarium or my pond there is always the stink of hydrogen sulfide ( fish don't seem to care.)

Comment: @blacksmith37 - Thanks , that gives bit peace of mind. But still if we could have some plants that can absorb some of the gases then it'd be great

Comment: Nitrogen is not toxic, you are breathing it in right now.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Right and I think it'll be helpful with plants growth as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were trying to use plants to mediate this you would need to approach it at some other point. No plant in the hole or around it will "absorb" gases to reduce the ppm below detectable threshold.

Comment: That's sad news but atleast would it help reduce a bit ?

Comment: That's not really how gasses work. Maybe try to use some REALLY smelly plants to overpower the smell?

Comment: Ok that kind of makes sense. Is there any plant which won't affect the building foudnation with its roots and drink lots of water ?